# Парсинг на python проблема с циклом

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть список товаров с ценами, нужно парсить и вводить Товар: цена, не знаю как сделать с циклом, выводится либо одинаковая цена, либо одинаковый товар
Нужно в одном цикле перебрать два значения
Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
URL_TEMPLATE = "#####"
r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
product_prices = soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "product-item-price-current"})
product_names = soup.find_all('a', class_='title')
for all in product_prices:
   prod_price = all.text.strip()
   for name in product_names:
     prod_name = name.text.strip()
     print(f"{prod_name}: {prod_price}")
```

UPD
Так не работает тоже:

```
products = soup.find_all("tr", class_ = "product-item-row-card")
for prod in products:
    product_name = soup.find('a', class_ = 'title').text.strip()
    product_price = soup.find("span", class_ = "product-item-price- 
    current").text.strip()
    print(f"{product_name}: {product_price}")
```

Comment: Проблема в том что у вас запускается 2 цикла. Обычно при парсинге находится блок с нужной информацией (где находится имя, цена итд), этот блок перебирается циклом и вытаскивается нудная инфа

Comment: так один товар и одна цена: 

products = soup.find_all("tr", class_ = "product-item-row-card")
for product in products:
    product_name = soup.find('a', class_='title').text.strip()
    product_price = soup.find("span", {"class" : "product-item-price-current"}).text.strip()
    print(f"{product_name}: {product_price}")

Comment: @vlad, если `a.title` находится в одном логическом блоке с ценой, то и вытаскивать их нужно вместе. Мб по общему тегу уровнем выше. А то кривовато выглядит алгоритм. Вы, конечно, можете разом перебирать и `product_prices`, и `product_names`, если уверены, что они пересекаются: тут или по индексам перебираете - берете размер одного из списков и перебираете по `i`, а в цикле достаете значения как `product_prices[i]`, и `product_names[i]`, либо используете `zip`: `for name, price in zip(product_names, product_prices)`. Но это, по-мне, костыли

Comment: @gil9red, Костыли не нужны, учусь как правильно. Все находится в теге <tr>.
Дальше беру все из <a> - отображаю и беру все из <span> - отображаю

Comment: И ещё не используйте `all` как имя переменной, это встроенная функция питона

Comment: А можете пояснить, что конкретно не работает в нижнем блоке кода?

Comment: @Proksima отображает так 
Товар1: Цена1
Товар1: Цена1
Товар1: Цена1

Тоесть он не перебирает все значения

Comment: ссылку на сайт датите?